# htaccess redirect all pages with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need all pages on my site to be redirected to home.php with query string and the page as parameter

examples:

```
   www.site.com/abcd
-> www.site.com/home.php?page=abcd

   www.site.com/abcd/file.php
-> www.site.com/home.php?page=abcd/file.php

   www.site.com/file.php?a=b&c=d
-> www.site.com/home.php?page=file.php&args="a=b&c=d"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ home.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will do what you want, except for the parameters passed, they will show up in there original form:

```
www.site.com/file.php?a=b&c=d -> www.site.com/home.php?page=file.php&a=b&c=d
```

Comment: thanks, and FYI I figured out how to parse the parameters in PHP:  $args = '?';

foreach ($_GET as $g => $g2) {
 if ($g<>"page") {$args .= $g."=".$g2."&";}
}

$args = substr($args,0,-1);